# TimeSpan.Add() used in conjunction with TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, timespan

Morning,
Im trying to add 1 minute to an existing TimeSpan object. I wanted to avoid declaring a new TimeSpan object and figured the following code would work:

```
ts3.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

the MSDN info states the TimeSpan.Add method signature as:

```
public TimeSpan Add(TimeSpan ts)
```

and the TimeSpan.FromMinutes method as:

```
public static TimeSpan FromMinutes(double value)
```

Add needs a TimeSpan object and FromMinutes returns a TimeSpan object so i dont understand why i cant use both in conjunction, as stated in the first code block.

Id appreciate it if someone could point out where i have gone wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: "I wanted to avoid declaring a new TimeSpan object"... why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *can* use them in conjunction - but you need to be aware that `TimeSpan` is itself immutable - you need to use the return value:

```
TimeSpan result = ts3.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

Or you could always assign back to the same variable:

```
ts3 = ts3.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

Personally I'd use operator overloading though:

```
TimeSpan result = ts3 + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
```

or

```
ts3 += TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
```

Comment: Particular reason why latter is preferred?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: I find it easier to read, that's all. It also stops you from failing to use the result...

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you very much for you fast + complete answer. I will implement ur preferred approach.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a new TimeSpan for adding a minute to an existing TimeSpan.

the only way is myTimeSpan.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(xxx)) and use the returned value as the result of the addition

Comment: +1 for pointing out that i hadnt realised it was immutable. Thanks very much for your time!

Comment: ...or, more readably, `myTimeSpan + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(bla)`

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use timespans the way you indicated.  Nothing in your question indicates any problem.

Comment: As Mr Skeet and Eyossi have pointed out, i had failed to realise that TimeSpan is immutable.

Comment: @HansRudel - And I failed to realize that you are simply overlooking the correct value being returned to you :-)

Comment: likewise bro. Got to love Mondays!